# Java Android. Работа в фоновом режиме. Класс Surface

Tags: java, android, видео, udp, screenshots

Я искал как сделать запись происходящего на экране Android. Нашел, [вот на сайте](http://www.fandroid.info/kak-sozdat-prilozhenie-dlya-zapisi-ekrana-android-smartfona/)

Реализовал (с помощью `MediaProjection`). И оно работает так: я кликая на кнопку - начинаю запись, кликая на нее еще раз - заканчиваю. Потом я создал еще одну кнопку - при нажатии на нее, у меня в VideoView выводится все что я записал (с помощью `.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(recordService.getPathVideo()));`).
Но мне нужно это видео каким-то образом передать через сеть - на мой `UDP-сервер`. Он у меня уже реализован. Проблема в том, что и как отправить на сервер с помощью `UDP-протокола`. Во что конвертировать видео и как это сделать?

На скрине ниже написано, что можем взять Surface и отослать (взял его на [этом сайте](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Notifications)). 
Во-первых, как его "развернуть" на `Android`, то есть если я даже передам и приму его - то как дальше его показать пользователи, показать само видео, которое записалось?
Во-вторых, как отослать через `UDP-протокол`, а то как там Bitmap отсылать я знаю - там я просто отсылаю массив байтов. А в этому случае (видео) - не знаю как сделать

[image]
В идеале оно должно выглядеть так: клиент (`Android`) записывает видео - передает его на `UDP-сервер` (на компе), а тот просто перекидывает ему же его же (для начала это мне подойдет). Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать такой процесс?

UPDATE:
Может кто-то знает как работать с Parcel или как с помощью него можно вывести это записанное видео на экран?